# Is it normal for a large HOSTS file where all entries point to 0.0.0.0 to take a very long time to update the DNS cache?

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, hosts-file

I have an old laptop (Core 2 Duo U9400 @ 1.4Ghz) which struggles with the modern internet. I wanted to try adding one of the exceptionally large (~900,000 entries) hosts files which are common to Android phones to this Windows system to see if it improves internet response time.

I've never attempted this before on Windows and it seems as though the "Service Host: DNS Client" is attempting to resolve all of these entries for its cache.

The DNS cache is a good thing. Except for the fact that the caching service has been running for about 30 minutes now and still going. I know that there are an exceptional amount of entries here but should it take this long when they all point to 0.0.0.0? There shouldn't need to be anything to resolve.

I am using the following hosts entries from this XDA post:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/mod-ultimate-hosts-852101-entries-t3634123

I am running Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the 0.0.0.0 with 127.0.0.1 ? 0.0.0.0 is technically routable [default route], & also used by DHCP & as such will be sent to the entire segment; so it would be worth trying a non-routable address.

Comment: This was my thought as well. There is no observable difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0.